# Properties of ODE without solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I stumbled over a nice exercise in a Textbook about ODEs, witch i couldn't figure out yet. Here's the Problem

$ u''=-u-u^{3}-ku'$ $,k >0$

show that for every k there exists a nontrival solution, with $ t \in [0,\infty[$ and $ \lim_{x\to \infty} u(x) = 0$

To solve this i think one have to use some Theorems. Can someone help me out? I am not interested in a particular solution, just in general some hints or theorems which help me out. Thank you!

greetings, 
linda

Comment: It's tempting to multiply by $u'$ and integrate over time intervals $[0,t]$.

Comment: Thank you. I quite dont understand $u'u''=-u*u''-u^3u'-k*u'^2$ und now integrating how does this help?

Comment: Calculate $\frac{d}{dt}(u'(t)^2)$, $\frac{d}{dt}(u(t)^4)$, and use the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Remember that if $f(t)\geq 0$ then $\int_0^t f(s) ds\geq 0$.

Comment: so the first term is $2*u'*u''$ and $ 4*u(t)^3*u' $ so integrating the whole ode and plugging in, how can manage to evalute the other two terms $ -u*u'' and -k*u'^2 $?

Comment: there is no $uu''$ (check again), and remember $u(t)^2>0$. The whole point is to show that $|u(t)|$ cannot exceed some expression involving only initial data.  Then you use a theorem about global existence, under the local Lipschitz condition: that the only way a solution can cease to exist is by becoming infinite (which would imply exceeding any value).

Comment: understand. so after multiplying and integrating i got $ 1/2*u'^2=-1/2*u^2-1/4*u^4- integral{k*u'^2} $ => u'=0 ? it that correct?

Comment: No that does not follow. Let $v(t) = (u')^2/2 + u^2/2 + u^4/4$ then $v(t) \geq 0$ since all terms are positive and your calculations above shows that $\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = -k(u')^2 < 0$. Thus $v(t)$ is decreasing and we have $0\leq v(t) \leq v(0)$ for all $t$. Other things you can try to show from these observations: 1) $v(t)$ has a finite limit as $t\to\infty$ (monotone convergence theorem) and 2) $u(t)$ is bounded for all $t$. This takes care of existence (see Oskar’s comment above). Showing $\lim_{t\to\infty}u(t) = 0$ requires some more work though.

Comment: I don't know if it counts as cheating, but if we convert this equation to the first order system, the origin would be a stable equilibrium for all $k > 0$ (stable focus for $0 < k < 2$ and stable node for $k >= 2$). It's not hard to construct the ellipse without contact that surrounds origin. All trajectories that start at ellipse enter the compact domain and never leave it: there is a theorem which states that in such case trajectory exists for all $t > 0$.What makes me suspicious is that question asks only for existence of such trajectory,whereas this reasoning proves there are many of them.

Comment: @Winther Gronwall's inequality for the function $t\mapsto |u'(t)|^2=:\phi(t)$ in the form $\phi(t)'+2k\phi(t)<0$ should do.